# What is the smallest drone ever made?

Tags: under-250-grams

There are [nanocars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanocar) and nanomachines in general.

I would be very impressed if a nano drone or nano-UAV existed, however, I would not be surprised if there has been something built on the microscopic scale.

What is the world record for the smallest drone ever made?

Answer (score 4):

Previous answers have covered commercial ones. I believe the smallest self-powered drone is the piccolissimo. It is 2.5g and passively stable.

Here is the Wikipedia article on it:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piccolissimo

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with making a nano drone is that for it to be what is commonly considered a ‘drone’, it needs to be able to be controlled via radio waves and/or be programmed to complete specific tasks.

The trouble this introduces is that to receive radio waves effectively, the receiver antenna needs to be around one-half wavelength (AFAIK), so nano-scale drones are not practical for current technology.

Two very well-known ‘micro’ drones are the Cheerson CX-10 and the Hubsan Q4 H111, both of which are approximately 25mm by 25mm.

Of course, this is only considering consumer drones. Scientific laboratories, universities and the military likely have much smaller hardware.

Comment: Again, as in the other question, my question mentions nano-UAV's too :)

Comment: @user1271772 sorry - what other question do you mean?

Comment: You answered my question about the earliest ever UAV in recorded history :)

Comment: @user1271772 ah sorry - I think I misunderstood then. I have amended my answer to the other post as well. When it comes to nano aircraft, I am unaware of any that exist at present but I’d be interested to see what other answers there are :)

Comment: Yea I doubt there's any nano-UAVs out there. Therefore the question is, what is the smallest one in existence, and you've already given a good answer. Unfortunately if I upvote you, you will not get the points because you can get a maximum of 200 points per day!

Comment: @user1271772 no worries - sorry that I wasn’t able to completely answer your question, I hope you get the answer you’re looking for!